# Build Definition

Tags: build-definition

When creating a new build definition, I cannot see the other solution configuration.  I have three  solution configurations: debug, test, and release.

In the process tab > 1.required > item to build > configuration to build

I can only see two of the configuration:
[image]

Is there something I am miss here?

Comment: The dialog would have to load and parse the solution to infer all the possible solution configurations. I suspect here they are just listing the 4 default combinations. As the dialog says, type in the ones that you want if they aren't listed.

Comment: @StephenConnolly - that is the answer, you should post it as one. Maybe emphasise the **type in your configuration**

Answer (score 1):

The dialog would have to load and parse the solution to infer all the possible solution configurations. I suspect here they are just listing the 4 default combinations. As the dialog says, **type in the ones that you want if they aren't listed**.